# GET {httr} returns a Bad Request response

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to scrape html elements of the url stored in`searchlink`. The only method that worked for me is`htmlTreeParse` {XML}.However it's not returning the elements I'm looking for. example:`img[@title='Add to compare']`

```
searchlink <- "http://www.realtor.ca/Map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertyTypeId=300&TransactionTypeId=2&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&LongitudeMin=-114.52066040039104&LongitudeMax=-113.60536193847697&LatitudeMin=50.94776904194829&LatitudeMax=51.14246522072541&PriceMin=0&PriceMax=0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&ParkingSpaceRange=0-0&viewState=m&Longitude=-114.063011169434&Latitude=51.0452194213867&ZoomLevel=11&CurrentPage=1" 

doc <- htmlTreeParse(searchlink,useInternalNodes = T)


   classes <- xpathSApply(doc,"//img[@title='Add to compare']",function(x){xmlGetAttr(x,'class')})
```

the result of running classes above:

```
list()
```

I have also tried `readLines` and `GET` {httr} but they both returned an error in reading the url. I am guessing it's because of the special characters in the url but don't know how to go about fixing it. Response is given below:

```
Response [http://www.realtor.ca/Map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertyTypeId=300&TransactionTypeId=2&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&LongitudeMin=-114.52066040039104&LongitudeMax=-113.60536193847697&LatitudeMin=50.94776904194829&LatitudeMax=51.14246522072541&PriceMin=0&PriceMax=0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&ParkingSpaceRange=0-0&viewState=m&Longitude=-114.063011169434&Latitude=51.0452194213867&ZoomLevel=11&CurrentPage=1]
  Date: 2014-12-01 16:46
  Status: 400
  Content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
  Size: 324 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the one `#` in the url, I just replaced with a `?`

```
library("httr")
url <- "http://www.realtor.ca/Map.aspx?CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertyTypeId=300&TransactionTypeId=2&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&LongitudeMin=-114.52066040039104&LongitudeMax=-113.60536193847697&LatitudeMin=50.94776904194829&LatitudeMax=51.14246522072541&PriceMin=0&PriceMax=0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&ParkingSpaceRange=0-0&viewState=m&Longitude=-114.063011169434&Latitude=51.0452194213867&ZoomLevel=11&CurrentPage=1"
res <- GET(url)
tt <- content(res)
```

then parse the html content in `tt`

Comment: Thanks Scott it worked!! but I'm still not able to extract the html elements I need. I am trying to parse the attributes of all the "add to compare" buttons on that webpage. I've tried `xpathSApply(tt,"//img[@title='Add to compare']",function(x){xmlGetAttr(x,'class')})` but it returns NULL. I'm not sure where the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: if you do `xpathSApply(tt, "//img[@title]", xmlGetAttr, name="title")` I don't see any title with attributes with `Add to compare`

Comment: which is why it's strange to me because if you inspect the element on the webpage, you'll see the following: `<img id="com_img_15023510" class="compareIcon com-15023510" src="/Presentation/Images/common/icons/compare_unselected.png" alt="Add to compare" title="Add to compare">`. so for some reasons, when reading the html , seems like the entire html code is not being scraped.

Comment: you may want to try `RSelenium` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html which can automate web browser actions in R, theres lots of example questions in SO

Comment: I have a feeling that the reason the elements are not being pulled is because they're located in the side panel and hence in a different frame. I will try `switchToFrame`{RSelenium} to see if it'll work. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: By looking more carefully at the webpage, I realized that the side panel, where the results are displayed, is a dynamic div and it updates every time the browser is resized. So it made me wonder, when I use `htmlTreeParse`{XML} or`GET`{httr} or `readLines`, does it capture ALL the html elements from the source including the dynamic div's/panels, or does it instantaneously parse the source and doesn't give the page a chance  to fully load first? Sorry for the numerous questions but this is really bugging me! I cannot proceed with my project if I cannot scrape the elements I need.